# Empty drop down lists in ssrs report

Tags: drop-down-menu, ssrs-2008, ssas

Ok, I am a bit stumped here.  I am using an ssas cube as a data source for numerous reports.  The reports all have a start and end week or month parameter.  When I run the reports as me, they run fine.  However, when I log in as another user on the system, the drop down lists are empty.  So, I can't run the reports because there is nothing to choose from in the week or month drop down list.  Note that I have tried with embedded and shared datasets.  Is that a dataset security setting that I am missing?  This is very odd.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, the only way I could get the data to come up was to change the ssas role permissions to be full control (administrator) for the cube.  That sure seems wrong.  But Ive everything else I can think of.  These reports are read only, and just have a from date, to date, and then present the corresponding data from the cube between the two dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you defined any security on your cube?

Also, check the impersonation information of the data source defined in your analysis services project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187597.aspx

Comment: It was security.  Hadn't defined role correctly in ssas.  Thanks!